# Verify numeric fields in JSON response have values till two decimal points using Karate

Tags: json, karate

JSON Response:
[
  {
    "actNum": "12345678",
    "prodType": "Test",
    "period": {
      "January": [
        {
          "name": "Jake",
          "rRar": 12.34,
          "lRar": 340.45,
          "address": "New York"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jorge",
          "rRar": 28.78,
          "lRar": 250.49,
          "address": "Chicago"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

I have to verify that numeric fields in the above response rRar and lRar should have value till two decimal points like 12.78,32.56.

Could anyone please help me if this validation can be done using Karate API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def nums = $response..rRar
* def temp = $response..lRar
* karate.appendTo(nums, temp)
* def strs = karate.map(nums, function(x){ return x + '' })
* match each strs == '#regex [0-9].+\\.[0-9]{2}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter for your response, when I used the above code, I'm getting error as no step-definition method match found for: karate.appendTo(nums, temp).
Here we are using this method for adding them to an array, is that correct understanding?

Comment: @suvi yes. please upgrade to the latest version

Comment: Okay sure..
Could you please let me know what we are trying to do here using 
function(x){ return x + '' } 
and what is the value of x here?

Comment: @suvi think of `map` as a loop over an array to create another array, `x` will be passed each value in the given list or array, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Comment: okay, are we using x + '' to have space between the values?
karate.appendTo is available in version 0.9.3 or higher, so in the lower version, can't we achieve this validation as karate.appendTo() is not available in lower versions?
Note: My organization is still using 0.9.2.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, for the clarifications. Have a Good Day :)