# How to merge multiple array in karate framework?

Tags: javascript, karate

I can add multiple array using Javascript with below code but when I apply same in Karate framework, it gives me error. Any help resolving this issue.

**Javascript:**

```
var array1 = ["02","03"];
var array2 = ["24","21"];
var array3 = ["12","13"];

function mergeElementsAtIndex(array1, array2, array3) {
      var newArray = array1.map(function(value, index) 
      {
        return value + array2[index] + array3[index];
      });
        return newArray;
    }

 - List item

merged_array = mergeElementsAtIndex(array1, array2, array3)
```

**Same in Karate:**

```
* def mydate = 
    """
    function (array1, array2, array3) {
      var newArray = array1.map(function(value, index) 
      {
        return value + array2[index] + array3[index];
      });
        return newArray;
    }
    """
* def newdissue = mydate(array1, array2, array3)
```

**I am getting error as**:

```
*** step failed: testing.feature:97 - javascript evaluation failed: mydate(array1, array2, array3), TypeError: issueMonth.map is not a function in <eval> at line number 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for above issue:

```
* def mydate = 
"""
function (array1,array2,array3) {
  array1=karate.append(array1);
  array2=karate.append(array2);
  array3=karate.append(array3);
  var c = [];

      for(var i=0;i<Math.max(array1.length,array2.length,array3.length); i++)
    {
        c.push((array1[i]|| 0)+(array2[i]|| 0)+(array3[i]|| 0))
    }
    return c
}
"""
* def expireDate = mydate(expireMonth,expireDay,expireYear)
```

Comment: I'm totally confused. I think you need to be looking at `karate.map()` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61882279/143475

Answer (score 1):

Use `karate.append()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def temp1 = [1, 2, 3]
* def temp2 = karate.append(temp1, [4, 5], [6, 7])
```

Comment: '''
var array1 = ["02","03"];
var array2 = ["24","21"];
var array3 = ["12","13"];
'''
My expected result from above merge is
'''
newarray = ["022412","032113"]
'''
append would give me 
'''
newarray = ["02","03","24","21","12","13"]
'''
I used append for something else and able to find the solution.